# Is $L_{\infty}(G)^{**}$ a without order Banach algebra?

Tags: banach-algebras

A Banach algebra **A** is *without order* if for all $x \in A$, $xA=\{0\}$ implies $x=0$, or, for all $x \in A$, $Ax=\{0\}$ implies $x=0$. If $G$ is a compact abelian group then $L_{\infty}(G)$ is a Banach algebra with the convolution product and its second dual is a Banach algebra with the first Arens product. I like know if $L_{\infty}(G)^{**}$ is a without order Banach algebra.

Comment: One thing which might help with calculations is the following fact: if $A$ is any Banach algebra whose underlying Banach space is isomorphic to $C(K)$ for some $K$, then $A$ is Arens regular. (This works by using the WAP characterization of Arens regularity that is due, I think, to John Pym, together with the fact that every bounded linear map $C(K)\to C(K)^*$ is weakly compact.)

Comment: Would you mind if I mentioned this question to my colleague Garth Dales? If you are a PhD student or a postdoc, and would prefer to keep this problem for yourself to work on, then let me know; I am sure Garth would respect that preference. If you are happy discussing the question non-pseudonymously, you could even contact him yourself

Comment: I thank you for your indications. I don't have problem with that you consult your colleague Garth Dales. In fact I would be very grateful. I send an email to you, but  I have received no reply.  @YemonChoi

Comment: I got your email, sorry for not replying. Garth and I have both been rather busy; I will pass this question on to him